# Able to setcookie in localhost but not in remote site

Tags: php, cookies, localhost, authentication

I'm just now started to learn php. The following code in php runs in localhost and I can see the cookie in localhost. But not in the remote host. The site I uploaded the same php file is http://ptcplugins.org/Cookie.php What would be the problem?

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
$name = "auth";
$value = "67161f35a519741aa2cf5848e4d1e46e7f7c09b2";
$domain = "ptcplugins.org";
$path = '/';
$secure = FALSE;
$expire = 0;

setcookie($name, $value);

foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value) 
    {
    setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path);
}
?>
```

Comment: Could it be that you're looking for ptcplugins.com in your cookie observation, but the code above is setting for ptcplugins.org?

Comment: Link fixed. Now both are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure);
```

I don't think you want to be looping through $_COOKIE, those are the cookies that have already been set.

Comment: `setcookie(    $name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly )` I've tested this too. Both failed. So I just commented the other codes and focus on simple one.